# Starability result default max stars

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm using starability library for ratings. However, instead of using the 5 stars default rating of starability, I'd like to make it 3. It works when the user is required to insert the rating:

```html
<legend class="input-label" id="priority-label">Priority: </legend>
<fieldset class="starability-basic">
  <input type="radio" id="no-rate" class="input-no-rate" name="priority" value="0" checked aria-label="No priority." />
  <input type="radio" id="first-rate1" name="priority" value="1" />
  <label for="first-rate1" title="Terrible">1 star</label>
  <input type="radio" id="first-rate2" name="priority" value="2" />
  <label for="first-rate2" title="Not good">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="first-rate3" name="priority" value="3" />
  <label for="first-rate3" title="Average">3 stars</label>
</fieldset>
```

[This is the rating selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yImIv.png)

However, when it comes to displaying the result, it still shows me 5 possible stars. I've tried to look into it but couldn't find a solution:

```html
<p class="starability-result" data-rating="<%= entry.priority %>">
  Rated: <%= entry.priority %> stars
</p>
```

[This is what the result display looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krk4E.png)

Comment: Assuming you're referring to [this Starability](https://github.com/LunarLogic/starability) library, then it's just CSS. You can just remove the last 2 stars from the HTML. If that's not the library you're using, please edit the question to include a link to the correct one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it is the library, however, in the result display there are no lines to remove. I edited the question and added 2 pictures in order to make what I meant it clearer. In the result display I'd like to display 3 stars in total, not 5 .

Comment: So you need to find where in your HTML the result is rendered and remove the 2 stars there too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What can I remove? My display result Html just look like this: `<p class="starability-result" data-rating="<%= entry.priority %>">
  Rated: <%= entry.priority %> stars
</p>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is

Comment: `entry.priority` is just a property of an object that I render in my home.ejs and stores a value, which is the rating from 1 to 3 @RoryMcCrossan